# Threaded comments in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, tree

I would like to be able to make inserts in a tree data structure (like the one doing comments on Disqus, Hacker News etc). And it would be nice to do it in a clever functional way.

Example

```
(def cmts [{:name "Abi" :id 1 :text "Great question" :children nil}
           {:name "Bib" :id 2 :text "What about zippers?" :children
            [{:name "Linus" :id 3 
              :text "I don't understand how to and insert 
                     children at a certain id with them"
              :children nil}]}])
```

The problem is how to insert a comment like this

```
(add-comment cmts :name "Iba" :text "I think so too!" :in-reply-to 1)
```

in a somehow concise/elegant way.

Or: what would be a simpler way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to do functional tree editing (editing neste data structures) then perhaps
the [zipper library](http://clojure.org/other_libraries#Other%20included%20Libraries-Zippers%20-%20Functional%20Tree%20Editing%20%28clojure.zip%29) is the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that there are very good functionality in the clojure.walk library that could do the trick. http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk